# ¿Por qué la conversión a byte me regresa los siguiente valores en Java?

Tags: java

¿Alguien me puede contestar el por qué me regresa estos valores?

El código es el siguiente:

```
package numeros;

public class Numeros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 127;
        byte y = (byte)(x + 1);

        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        System.out.println("y = " + y);

    }

}
```

**Output:**

> x=127 
>   y=-128

Comment: Mira este enlace, creo que te resolverá las dudas pero, para empezar, es por la capacidad que tiene una variable tipo byte ;). http://blog-programando-ando.blogspot.com/2013/10/tipo-byte-en-java.html

Answer (score 4):

Un byte son 8 bits. Por tanto, los valores que puedes guardar van desde
`00000000` hasta `11111111`.

Si asumimos que los valores son todos positivos, esto significaría que los valores permitidos van desde 0 hasta 255, pero el tipo byte en Java se considera un tipo de entero: tiene valores positivos y negativos.

La forma de guardar los números negativos es lo que se llama [complemento a 2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos). Básicamente se guarda el "negativo de un número" y se le suma uno. Como consecuencia de esto, todos los números negativos tienen un 1 como primer bit.

Por tanto, el mayor valor positivo que puedes guardar en un byte es:

```
01111111 (127)
```

Si a este valor le sumas 1, obtienes

```
10000000 (-128)
```

Que es el menor número posible (el mayor número negativo) que se puede guardar en un byte.

Por tanto la suma ha provocado un *overflow* (desbordamiento) y te has ido de un extremo al otro de los posibles valores.

Es el equivalente a tener el odómetro de un vehículo en 999999 y hacer un kilómetro más, pasando a 000000:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una variable de tipo `byte` no puede almacenar un número superior a **127 o menor a -128.**

En tu código estás asignando a la variable `y` el valor de `x` **(127) más uno (128).**

Te recomiendo leer sobre [tipos de datos](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=419:tipos-de-datos-java-tipos-primitivos-int-boolean-y-objeto-string-array-o-arreglo-variables-cu00621b&catid=68&Itemid=188).

Comment: El problema de esta respueta es que es un enlace, por sí misma no da ninguna explicación de lo que está pasando.